# How can i force image to stick to the div under it till 768px in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying these images to be responsive but also stick to the div under it. I used `margin-top` in `negative` to overlap the images on the above. So when I try to shrink the `width` of the browser the certain position of the images get disturbed. As the image given is and it should be same as it is at least till `768px` :

[Images Should be look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upcmg.jpg)

But Images when I try to shrink browser the position of images get disturbed. Images names are `fluffy1.png, hawkster1.png, tootie1.png`. I have also used media queries but images position disturbed every `50px` (averagely).

[Disturbed Position Images 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwewo.jpg)

[Disturbed Position Images 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSwBb.jpg)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid book-div">
    <h1 class="advertisment-paragraph">IN THE SPOTLIGHT...</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container main-book-div">
            <div class="row padding-book-div">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="book-cover img-responsive" src="../1/1/Bookcover.jpg" alt="Bookcover" width="300" height="300">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 main-book-paragraph">
                    <h1>Tongue Twits Book</h1>
                    <p>The special day arrive for Tottie to go to Rainbow
                    Park. Her brothers tagged along to have fun! This would be her brothers first time on roler coaster.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">BUY NOW</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img class="img-responsive hawkster2" src="../1/1/Hawkster1.png" alt="Hawkster2" width="100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img class="img-responsive  tootie2" src="../1/1/Tootie1.png" alt="tootie2" width="150" height="100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="../1/1/Fluffs1.png" alt="Fluffs2" class="img-responsive fluffy2" width="80" height="100">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid coloring-section">
    <h1></h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.book-div
 {
   background-color:white;
 }
 .main-book-div
 {
    background-color: rgb(200,199,255);
 }
 .book-cover
 {
    margin:10% 0 0 5%;
    border:5px solid black;
 }
 .padding-book-div
 {
    padding-bottom:5%;
 }
 .main-book-paragraph
 {
    margin-top:5%;
 }
 .main-book-paragraph>h1
 {
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:3em;
    margin-left:-40%;

 }
 .main-book-paragraph>p
 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size:1.6em;
    margin-left:-40%;
    font-family: Calibri Light;
    line-height:50px;
 }
 .main-book-paragraph>a
 {
    padding:2% 7%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color:rgb(223,28,70);
    margin-left:-40%;
  }
  .hawkster2
  {
    position:relative;
    margin:-58% 0 0 100%;
  }
 .tootie2
 {
    position:relative;
    margin:-46.5% 0 0 70%;
 }
 .fluffy2
 {
   position:relative;
   margin:-19% 0 0 20%;
 }
 .coloring-section
{
  background-image:url("../1/tootiewriting.jpg");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  height:630px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Using position relative you would want to use `top` to offset the positioning, not `margin`. You are also using percentages so the margin will constantly fluctuate with the viewport being resized. At any rate, try using `top` instead of `margin`, I believe you'll get better results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query (`@media`) for specifying the device and use `top` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Dont use margin to position your image. That is not the correct way to do that.

For me, I will group the images into a div. Add CSS 'position relative' to the image div.

```
    <div class="imgDiv">
        <img class="img-responsive hawkster2" src="../1/1/Hawkster1.png" alt="example2" width="100">
        <img class="img-responsive  tootie2" src="../1/1/Tootie1.png" alt="example3" width="150" height="100">
        <img src="../1/1/Fluffs1.png" alt="example4" class="img-responsive fluffy2" width="80" height="100">
    </div>
```

Hence, place your images using the css like below. Adjust using top, bottom, left, right properties. Hope it help.

```
    <style>
      .imgDiv{
        position: relative;
      }
      .hawkster2
      {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 1rem;
      }
     .tootie2
     {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 9rem;
     }
     .fluffy2
     {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -2rem;
        right: 20rem;
     }
    </style>
```